# Different structure/content for posts from a custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, custom-taxonomy

I've a CPT: **Services** and created two posts underneath it. Now, both those posts have some static content which is different in structure and design from each other. How do I place that content in my `single-services.php` so that it gets showed up for the appropriate posts?

I have a vague idea of putting the two posts under separate categories or create a custom taxonomy but don't know how do I proceed after that or is there a completely different and easier method to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress allows to do this rather neatly for pages, supporting `page-$slug.php` and `page-$id.php` templates in hierarchy. Unfortunately it doesn't apply to posts and Custom Post Types.

So your options are either handling this inside `single-services.php` (in one file, or by further including other template files) or adjusting hierarchy to use custom templates for your posts as needed.

Comment: I guess I'll change them to pages, put them under the category of 'services' and remove the CPT completely. Thanks!